# Android RecyclerView change all item imageviews

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView  with some items.

I want to change all ImageView image on items (without scroll)

My part code in onBindViewHolder is :

```
int count = parent.getChildCount();
v = parent.getChildAt(position);
while(i<count)
   if (i != position) {
      v = parent.getChildAt(i);
      ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgPlaySound);
      imageView1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.playsound);
      LinearLayout linearSeek1 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linearSeek);
      linearSeek1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
   i++;
}
```

This part code is working fine but if I add some items to my RecyclerView and scrolling my items my code cannot access to my all items

My custom RecyclerView class is separate file of activity code

Comment: RecyclerView creates all the views as the user scrolls and recycles the views that the user has scrolled through (thus the name recyclerview). You can only update views that are currently visible to the user. Also, you should be using a ViewHolder to hold all the views and access them via the `holder` instance (holder.imageview.setImageResource(...)).
Good Readings:
- http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html

Comment: Thanks, I have a full RecyclerView and it works but i have that problem

Answer (score 3):

Add each view from onBindViewHolder to an ArrayList then loop through this ArrayList and perform your action.

```
    ArrayList<ViewHolder> views = new ArrayList<>();//call in the constructor make it a class variable so it can accessed globally;
```

then on your "onBindViewHolder" do this

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

  views.add(holder)
}
```

now you can loop through the arraylist and set your views

```
int count = views.size();
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
  YourViewHolder v = views.get(i); 
  //call imageview from the viewholder object by the variable name used to instatiate it
  ImageView imageView1 = v.imageViewFromHolder;
  imageView1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.playsound);
  LinearLayout linearSeek1 = v.linearLayoutFromHolder 
  linearSeek1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps..

```java
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) holder.itemView.getParent();
for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
    //your code here..
}
```